# PHP: Key not printing from session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, loops

## What I have:

I have a session array that I created from form input. Here's the var_dump():

```
array(1) { ["post"]=> array(4) { [671]=> string(1) "1" [672]=> string(1) "2" [673]=> string(1) "3" [537]=> string(1) "4" } }
```

## What I need:

For testing purposes, I need to output the array as follows:

```
Key: 671 Value: 1 
Key: 672 Value: 2 
Key: 673 Value: 2 
Key: 537 Value: 4
```

What I'm actually doing, is using each key for a SQL query e.g. WHERE id="671" OR id="672" etc.

## What I've tried:

```
while (list($key,$value) = each($_SESSION)){
    echo "<strong>Key:</strong> ".$key." <strong>Value:</strong> ".$value."<br />";
}
```

...which produces:

```
Key: post Value: Array
```

I've also tried:

```
foreach($_SESSION['post'] as $array)
{
    list($key,$value) = $array;
    echo "<strong>Key:</strong> ".$key." <strong>Value:</strong> ".$value."<br />";
}
```

...which produces:

```
Key: 1 Value:
Key: 2 Value:
Key: 2 Value:
Key: 4 Value:
```

...notice the keys/values are reversed and the keys are missing.

## My question:

How do I correctly output (loop) the keys and values of my session array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach($_SESSION['post'] as $key =>$val) {
     echo "Key:".$key;
     echo "val:".$val;
 }
```

In your case your are just trying to iterate through array value

```
foreach($_SESSION['post'] as $array)
```

You need the above mentioned code to retrieve keys.

Comment: please explain why code in question is not working

Comment: Note: Colon is in the wrong place and a period is missing before $val producing a syntax error - otherwise, it works.

Comment: Can anyone outline why this answer was down-voted?

Comment: @DominorNovus I am puzzled too..  I don't know what's wrong with answer :(

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
foreach($_SESSION['post'] as $key=>$value)
{
    echo "<strong>Key:</strong> ".$key." <strong>Value:</strong> ".$value."<br />";
}
```

When you just use this structure:

```
foreach($_SESSION['post'] as $array)
```

The loop will NOT look at the keys, so $array will be equal to a particular value each time through (hence the list method will assign that value to the first variable, and null to the second).

Comment: please explain why code in question is not working ...

Comment: Edited to explain why $key=>$value is necessary with foreach.

Comment: I accepted chandresh_cool's answer because he answered 17 seconds before you (is this the fairest approach in accepting answers?). I've up-voted your answer because the format of the outputted mark-up exactly matches the example in my question and you've also provided a broader explanation.

Comment: @DominorNovus i have added reason of your both approach you may find it helpful check my answer

Answer (score 1):

why first approach is not working

```
while (list($key,$value) = each($_SESSION)){
```

because you have multidimensional array and  you are assigning   array try and `post` is key of child array try instead

```
while (list($key,$value) = each($_SESSION['post'])){
    echo "<strong>Key:</strong> ".$key." <strong>Value:</strong> ".$value."<br />";
}
```

---

why second approach is not working

let see what your code does first

```
foreach($_SESSION['post'] as $array)
```

The first form loops over the array given by `$_SESSION['post']`. On each iteration, the value of the current element is assigned to `$array` and the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).

so it wont get you key  ([**live result**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vtSFbq)) so instead use

```
foreach($_SESSION['post'] as $key=>$value)
{
    echo "<strong>Key:</strong> ".$key." <strong>Value:</strong> ".$value."<br />";
}
```

Above will  additionally assign the current element's key to the `$key` variable on each iteration.

Comment: Up-voted for providing a solution for each of my attempted methods and for providing the most detailed context on why each method did not originally work. Further acknowledgment is due for your demanding of more explanatory solutions in the other provided answers. (Note: In general, not sure whether to accept answers based on response-time of first working solution or on overall quality of answer.)

Comment: @DominorNovus i would just say accept that answer which is most informative .. and time really doesnot really matter